# Get a JDBC query parser instance for use by Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-dtp

I've created a simple plugin which successfully uses a `DB2` parser from Eclipse's DTP, but it chokes when `JDBC` syntax such as `{d: '2014-07-03'}` is used.

How can I get a `SQLQueryParserManager` instance that will handle this syntax? (Currently I'm using `SQLQueryParserManagerProvider.getInstance().getParserManager("DB2 UDB", "V9.5")`, and my [previous trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24637250/446591) isn't helping in this case.